# How to solve this C bitwise university problem?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

## Problem

Given a sequence of N integer values (N > 1). Using at most one conditional operator(or conditional operator), the program must determine whether its is true that sequence is increasing. Loops on a program can only be used to enumerate elements of a sequence.

### Example

```c
  int arr[] = {10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5}; // Decreasing sequence 
  int arr2[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}; // Increasing sequence
```

### My solution

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
 
/*
  Returns num1 if num1 < num2 otherwise num2
*/
static int CompareNums(int num1, int num2)
{
  return (int)(((num1 + num2) - sqrt((num1 - num2) * (num1 - num2))) / 2);
}
 
static _Bool IsIncreasing(int arr[], size_t N)
{
  int min = arr[0];
  int res = 0;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < N - 1; i++)
  {
    min = CompareNums(arr[i + 1], min);
    /*If min equals to current processed num => it is decreasing sequence*/
    res = min ^ arr[i + 1];
  }
 
  return res;
}
 
int main(void)
{
  int arr[] = {10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5};
  int arr2[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
  int res = IsIncreasing(arr2, 6);
 
  if (res == 0)
  {
    printf("Decreasing\n");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Increasing\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

It has a problem, it's work fine with sequence from example, but doesn't work with sequence like this

```c
//It is a complex sequence, but idk how to make my code detect this sequences.
int arr[] = {10, 11, 6, 12, 13}
```

#### Restrictions

```c
//You can't use if inside for loop
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
  //can't do this
  if(bool)
  {
  }
  //and this also
  int a = a > b ? a : b
}

 //And also this
 while(a > b) 
 {
 }
```

You need to calculate is it increasing sequence or not inside function than check for it for display right string

```c
static _Bool IsIncreasing(int arr[], size_t N)
{
}

int main(void)
{
  int res = IsIncreasing(arr, N);
  if(res)
  {
   printf("Increasing");
  }
  else 
  {
   printf("Decreasing");
  }
}
```

So, I'm don't know how to write clean function which will calculate increasing/decreasing sequences, including errors sequences. I wan't any support or ideas or maybe ready solution how to do this.

Comment: The assignment is rather poorly worded and it isn't quite clear what its intent is. "If min equals to current processed num => it is decreasing sequence" This is completely untrue, you need to find a different (working) method.

Comment: @n.m. But this explanation of the problem is all what I have about it by my instructor. Also, "If min equals to current processed num => it is decreasing sequence" means, that for this moment in loop res > 0 => sequence is still increasing, otherwise it is decreasing. So, if we goes throught loop, it is wil be a right result. But it will not work with sequence like this 1 2 6 8.

Comment: Um sorry this statement is true, I misread it. But your implementation is wrong. You do `res = min ^ arr[i + 1];` in a loop, this overwrites `res` each time so that only the very last value is considered.